# wordpress can't use header function inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

am trying to redirect the page using a header location, but it seems using the header function inside a function causes the problem cannot modify header info, any ideas ?

PS : i've already cleared white spaces, new lines and such things before asking

Comment: "It seems" how? What happens? What errors do you get? In general, it won't matter where you call the header command from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only option was putting the redirect outside the function

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has already *sent headers* by the time you are attempting to run your code.

This is covered in the WP Codex, but checkout [wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Comment: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop-single.php:33) in /wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897

Answer (score 1):

use javascript

```
echo "<script>location.href='http://www.disneyland.com'</script>";
```

You can only set headers once in php

Comment: but its for facebook authentication via SDK, it keeps redirecting back to facebook and facebook back to the site, really need headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the init hook to add and execute your function before the headers are sent.

Here is a link that will help you with hooks if you are unsure about them.

[Wordpress add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

And another link to the hook list for good measure
[Wordpress Hook List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

The "can't modify header info" error happens when output has already been sent to the browser.  Any echo, print, var_dump or html coming before an attempt to modify the headers will trigger this error.

Comment: and you suggest me to try send_headers ?

Comment: No, I am suggesting you use the `init` hook.

Comment: it didn't do it , i solved the problem by changing a small configuration in my server

Answer (score 0):

To use the PHP `header()` function, you need to use the WordPress `'init'` action hook.

For example, you could set the `X-UA-Compatible` header by adding the following to **functions.php**:

```
function http_headers() {
    header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');
}

add_action('init', 'http_headers');
```